# Beautiful Soup web scraping how to get all rows from table?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can i get all the table from the site there are more in the table but my code only returns 229rows. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://sosyalkedi.com/services"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for tr in soup.select("tr:not(:has(td[colspan], th))"):
    prev = tr.find_previous("td", attrs={"colspan": True})
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    all_data.append([prev.get_text(strip=True), *tds[:5]])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data,
    columns=["Parent", "ID", "Servis", "1000 adet fiyatı", "Minimum Sipariş", "Maksimum Sipariş"],
)
print(df.head())
```

I guess the problem is with getting the html file from the site in the first place. When i inspect, it shows different html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the `lxml` parser instead (`lxml` library is required):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
```

In this case, the parse tree generated by `html.parser` is different from the `lxml` generated tree. You can refer to [this table](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for comparison between supported parsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas.read_html()`

It might take a while though - it took me around 2 minutes, but got all 4041 tables.

here is just an example code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
tables = pd.read_html('https://sosyalkedi.com/services')
print(len(tables))
print(tables[0].head)
```